# ADF - Data control value doesn't exist

Tags: graph, oracle-adf, jspx

I am trying to create a graph out of a data control that I have created. The graph named myNewGraph is not showing up when I run my website, but when I preview the graph itself it is perfect.

JDeveloper autogenerates the graph, it generates this code, notice the `value`:

```
    <dvt:comboGraph id="comboGraph2" shortDesc="PriceMetrics"
                    value="#{bindings.myNewGraph.graphModel}"
                    subType="COMBINATION_VERT_ABS_2Y" customLayout="CL_NONE>
```

I have another graph I have created that has a similar code make-up. This one works perfectly.

```
    <dvt:comboGraph id="comboGraph1" shortDesc="PriceMetrics"
                    value="#{bindings.existingGraph.graphModel}"
                    subType="COMBINATION_VERT_ABS" customLayout="CL_NONE"
```

I believe it has something to do with the value, that is causing my `myNewGraph` to not work. Because when I replace it with the value of `existingGraph`, the graph displays, but it doesn't display the correct data, since it has the same value.

How do I generate the value in `bindings.myNewGraph.graphModel` because I believe that it doesn't technically exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must import the graph bindings into the webpagePageDef.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the preview in the editor showed the real graph data ? from the description you give it sounds as if your data isn't queried. I suggest you debug the business service you expose in the data control to see if there is a query executed. From your description it doesn't look like a problem with the binding EL or the graph

Frank